# why I have to set a implicitly type although I have interface added?

Tags: typescript

I have added a interface, so why I have to set a type on my function for each parameter ? (id, name, year)

```
interface trackType {
    id: string,
    name: string,
    year: number
}

const tracks: Array<string> = [];

function addTrack<trackType>(id, name, year) {
    
}
```

Comment: [Example](https://tsplay.dev/WvVbnW)

Comment: @captain-yossarian thanks! But how can I destruct track parameter with this interace ?

Comment: `function addTrack({ id, name, year }: TrackType) {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you should pass to `addTrack` the whole object.
Consider this example:

```js
interface TrackType {
  id: string,
  name: string,
  year: number
}

const tracks: Array<string> = [];

function addTrack({ id, name, year }: TrackType) { 
  
}
addTrack({ id: 'a', name: 'John', year: 100 })
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/WvVbnW)